# Windows 8.1 - USB Autorun not changing the icon

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, windows-8.1, icons

I have created an autorun.inf file with the commands below :

> [Autorun]
>
> label = MyName
>
> icon = myicon.ico

The purpose of this autorun file is the change the default name Removable Disk to MyName and to change it's icon to myicon.ico.

*Last week it was working well in my Windows 8.1. Yesterday i accidentally unplugged my USB without using safe removal of drive. After that when i plugged in it prompted and said to "Scan and Repair the drive ". I clicked scan and it started but since it was taking too long to scan i cancelled the operation. My intention was to re-run the scan. Then i safely removed my drive and plugged it again. Then i went to "This PC" and looked for the drive. The drive had the default icon. So i performed the scan again and it finished quickly .Then i opened my drive and looked for my autorun.inf and myicon.ico file. It was there and since the name and icon didn't change i removed those two files. Then i created the autorun file and the icon file again and moved to my drive. I unplugged the drive after performing safe removal of the drive. The i plugged it again. Even now its not working as expected. I tried plugging it my other machine running Windows 7 and it worked normally i.e the icon got changed to myicon.ico and the name to MyName.*

I check my Autorplay setting and it was enabled. What is to be done to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

On This scenario I recommend you to **create a back up of the files** and **format your drive**. after formatting just **copy back the files** as well as your **autorun.inf file and myicon.ico files**. it will work for sure. give a try and tell me the result.

Comment: Sorry i can't do this. I'm having a 3TB Hard disk and i have about 2 TB of files. So i can't format my drive.

Comment: i was assuming you are using a pen drive.
the hdd issue is harder. i too had same . this is with that disk check utility of windows.